# How to set the size of photo before capturing on Android

Tags: android, image, camera, android-camera

I code the capturing photo by using surfaceView and surfaceHolder.

How to fix the size of image?

Comment: I mean default size of photo after taking is 2560x1920 but what I want is to fix its size to 600x600 :) 
I try to use p.setPictureSize(600, 600); but after I get its width and height it still return 2560x1920. Thank you for your kindness

Comment: did you find any solution so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    if (isPreviewRunning) {
        camera.stopPreview();
    }
    Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

    p.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
    //p.setPictureSize(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());
    p.setPictureSize(600,600);

    p.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_FLUORESCENT);

    p.setPreviewSize(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());

    camera.setParameters(p);
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```